# How to prevent inputs made with renderUI from resetting after they are hidden and displayed again?

Tags: r, shiny

A common scenario for many of my shiny apps is that there is a large list of potentially interesting filter variables (often 10 to 20), but I want to **avoid confusing the user with too many input widgets**.

Therefore, my strategy is usually as follows: 
**1.** Users may select filter variables. **2.** If at least one filter variable is selected, a renderUI is triggered, which contains one input widget per selected variable. **3.** The filter criteria are applied to the data and some output is generated.

The problem is that any change in step one (by adding or deleting a filter variable) eliminates all previously made choices from step two. This means that **all input widgets are unintentionally reset to their default values**. This prevents a smooth user experience. Any idea how to improve on this?

Here you can see what happens:

[image: Example of unintentional widget reset]

And here is the code to reproduce this behaviour:

```
library("shiny")
library("dplyr")
library("nycflights13")

df <- flights
filtervarsChoices <- c("origin","carrier")
originChoices <- unique(df$origin)
carrierChoices <- unique(df$carrier)


ui <- fluidPage(
  h3("1. Select Filter variables"),
  selectInput("filterVars", "Filter variables", filtervarsChoices, multiple = TRUE),
  uiOutput("filterConditions"),
  h3("Result"),
  tableOutput("average")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$filterConditions <- renderUI({
    req(input$filterVars)
    tagList(
      h3("2. Select Filter values"),
      if ("origin" %in% input$filterVars) {
        selectInput("originFilter", "Origin", originChoices, multiple = TRUE)
      },
      if ("carrier" %in% input$filterVars) {
        selectInput("carrierFilter", "Carrier", carrierChoices, multiple = TRUE)
      }
    )
  })

  output$average <- renderTable({
    if ("origin" %in% input$filterVars) {
      df <- df %>% filter(origin %in% input$originFilter)
    }
    if ("carrier" %in% input$filterVars) {
      df <- df %>% filter(carrier %in% input$carrierFilter)
    }
    df %>% 
      summarise(
        "Number of flights" = n(), 
        "Average delay" = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE)
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I just changed the title to make the relevance of the topic clearer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you render the UI element every time it is selected, and thus its selected choices are reset. We can solve this by only rendering the elements a single time, and showing or hiding them when applicable. We can do this with the `show` and `hide` functions from the `shinyjs` package, and by wrapping div's around the `selectInputs` as we create them. So each filter `x` gets a corresponding input called `xFilter` and a div wrapped around it called `div_x`.

Below is a working example. I have tried to make the code as general as possible, so that you would only have to supply additional elements in `filtervarsChoices` and in `choices_list` to extend with additional filters. I also modified the table that is outputted to show that the filters are working correctly.

Note that in the example below, hidden filters are still applied to the resulting `data.frame`. In order to only apply visible filters, the for loop should run over `input$filterVars` as shown by Till n the comments below.

I hope this helps!

[image]

```
library("shiny")
library("dplyr")
library("nycflights13")
library(shinyjs)

df <- flights
filtervarsChoices <- c("origin","carrier")
originChoices <- unique(df$origin)
carrierChoices <- unique(df$carrier)
# Create a list with the choices for the selectInputs.
# So the selectInput for 'origin', will get the choices defined in originChoices.
choices_list <- list('origin' = originChoices,
                     'carrier' = carrierChoices)


ui <- fluidPage(
  column(width=3,
         h3("1. Select Filter variables"),
         selectInput("filterVars", "Filter variables", filtervarsChoices, multiple = TRUE),
         uiOutput("filterConditions"),
         h3("Result"),
         tableOutput("average"),
         useShinyjs()
  ),
  column(width=3,
         h3("Applied filters"),
         htmlOutput('appliedfilters')

  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Render all selectInput elements.
  output$filterConditions <- renderUI({
    lapply(filtervarsChoices, function(x){
      shinyjs::hidden(div(id=paste0('div_',x),
                          selectInput(paste0(x,"Filter"), x, choices_list[[x]], multiple = TRUE)
      ))})
  })

  # Show all divs that are selected, hide all divs that are not selected.
  observeEvent(input$filterVars, ignoreNULL = F,
               {
                 to_hide = setdiff(filtervarsChoices,input$filterVars)
                 for(x in to_hide)
                 {
                   shinyjs::hide(paste0('div_',x))
                 }
                 to_show = input$filterVars
                 for(x in to_show)
                 {
                   shinyjs::show(paste0('div_',x))
                 }
               })

  output$appliedfilters <- renderText({
    applied_filters <- c()
    for(x in filtervarsChoices)  # for(x in input$filterVars)
    {
      if(!is.null(input[[paste0(x,'Filter')]]))
      {
        applied_filters[length(applied_filters)+1] = paste0(x,': ', paste(input[[paste0(x,'Filter')]],collapse=", "))
      }
    }
    paste(applied_filters,collapse='<br>')
  })

  output$average <- renderTable({

    # For all variables, filter if the input is not NULL.
    # In the current implementation, all filters are applied, even if they are hidden again by the user.
    # To make sure only visible filters are applied, make the loop run over input$filterVars instead of filterVarsChoices
    for(x in filtervarsChoices)  # for(x in input$filterVars)
    {
      if(!is.null(input[[paste0(x,'Filter')]]))
      {
        df <- df %>% filter(get(x) %in% input[[paste0(x,'Filter')]])
      }
    }

    unique(df[,c('origin','carrier')])

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Awesome! I usually try to avoid java script elements in my shiny apps, because I find it difficult to read (and because I have very little knowledge about it). But this solution is really elegant. I guess this is as concise and readable as it can get :-)

Comment: There is still one problem: Once we have set some filter conditions they will remain active even if the filter variables are deselected. For example if we select the filtervalue "JFK" for the filtervariable "origin" and then deselect this filtervariable, the filter condition is visually hidden, but still active in the background.

Comment: We can address this problem by replacing filtervarsChoices by input$filterVars in the the first for loop of the renderTable function. Then only the filter conditions of selected filter variables are applied.

Comment: @Till, I assumed this was the expected behavior, but I agree that it is very confusing for the user to have filters applied to the dataframe if he is not aware of that filter anymore. I have modified my answer so hidden filters are still applied, but a html element tells the user which filters are actively applied. I have also adjusted the explanation to include your comment so others that may use this code are aware of the differences. I hope you are OK with this :)